# How to convert arbitrary string to hexadecimal color code

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex

I've a list of arbitrary strings. I would like to convert these to a hexadecimal color code.

The code should not be random, as it is essential that the method must return the same color code each time I convert the same string.

**SOLUTION:**

```
public string GetColorCode(string value)
{
    var i = value.GetHashCode() & 0x00FFFFFF;
    return i.ToString("X6");
}
```

Comment: Am confused...you want to convert or map?

Comment: The solution should really be added as your own answer to the question, shouldn't it? I realize this would take the points from the answerer, but it would offer better content for later visitors (like me) and better follows the SO format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetHashCode()` as a starting point. Since `GetHasCode()` returns a full integer and you usually need just 3 bytes to define a color in `RGB`, you have to skip the noin significant part by doing either:

```
var color = str.GetHashCode() & 0x00FFFFFF;
```

or

```
 var color = str.GetHashCode()>>8;
```

this guarantee having same string, same color.

Comment: How can I convert this color integer into a hexadecimal color code? I've tried color.ToString("X"), but this does not always return a hexadecimal code with 6 digits.

Comment: `ToString("X6")` will add leading zeroes if necessary, if that's your problem.

Comment: @DennisMadsen I corrected the answer with >>8, the ToString("X6") as suggested by Rawlign is the way to go after my suggestion.